Using Variables Inside Ephemeral Model in dbt
I have a use case for dbt where I will reuse a CTE in two different Redshift models rs_model1 and rs_model2. The CTE applies several filter conditions that are relevant for both Redshift models. In order to avoid duplicate code and avoid that new relevant filters might be forgotten to add in one of the two models, I wanted to use an ephemeral model.
However, there is one difference between filtering the CTE as for rs_model1 I am only interested in all entries of table1 with form_id = 123 and in rs_model2 I am only interested in all entries of table1 with form_id = 111.
So for rs_model1, my CTE looks something like this:
WITH table1_cte AS (
      SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1
      WHERE
          filter_condition1
          AND filter_condition2
          AND filter_condition3
          AND form_id = 123
      QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col4) = 1
)

for rs_model2, it looks like this:
WITH table1_cte AS (
      SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1
      WHERE
          filter_condition1
          AND filter_condition2
          AND filter_condition3
          AND form_id = 111
      QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col4) = 1
)

Is there any way in dbt to dynamically pass a variable to my ephemeral model inside rs_model1 and rs_model2?
I already tried using
{{
    config(
        vars={'form_id': 123}
    )
}}

inside my rs_model1
and adjusting the ephemeral model to
WITH table1_cte AS (
      SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1
      WHERE
          filter_condition1
          AND filter_condition2
          AND filter_condition3
          AND form_id = {{ var('form_id') }}
      QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col4) = 1
)
SELECT * FROM table1_cte

but this only passed None as form_id to the ephemeral model when I tried to run rs_model1.

you might want to revisit how do you access that variable. If you are using a Python dictionary, you will need another way to access the variable in your model.

You can make a dbt macro where you put form_id as an argument. You can make a cte name a variable too:
    {% macro generate_cte_with_form_id(cte_name, form_id) %}
  WITH {{ cte_name }} AS (
      SELECT col1, col2, col3
      FROM {{ ref('table1') }}
      WHERE
          filter_condition1
          AND filter_condition2
          AND filter_condition3
          AND form_id = {{ form_id }}
      QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY col4) = 1
  )
{% endmacro %}

Then you can refer to your cte like this:
{{ generate_cte_with_form_id('table1_cte', var('form_id')) }}

SELECT * FROM table1_cte

